# Cómo puedo implementar Reactjs dentro de un proyecto Django?

Tags: python, django, reactjs

tengo el problema de que he comenzado un proyecto en Django pero ahora necesito implementar react. Al estar empezado el proyecto no se como deberia implentarlo, y todos los tutoriales que veo es cuando estas iniciando el proyecto.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Imagino que solo tendrás que incluir los javascript de react en la parte de las vistas. Si lo que necesitas es inicializar la configuración con webpack o npm es otra historia

Comment: Es añadir el react dentro del proyecto.

Comment: lo lograste implementar ?

Answer (score 0):

Con que esta el proyecto? javascript puro? si es asi, debes crear un proyecto react, la manera mas facil es con create-react-app:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app nombredetuprojecto
```

ya eso trae incluido webpack, y solo deberias migrar tu js, a jsx y react.

Luego, usas los endpoints que te da Django. y los conectas a react, para lo cual, es recomendable que uses redux, asi te queda el codigo mas ordenado.

Espero haberte ayudado